# Can I carry large sum of cash (>10k EUR) in my hand luggage?

Tags: air-travel, schengen, europe, money

I will be flying between two, both EU and Schengen-area countries.

Can I take on-board large sum of cash (more than 10k euros) in my hand luggage? I know I need to declare this cash at customs but do I need to pay any fee for that? Can the airline have any regulations that would prohibit flying with large sum of cash?

Comment: I don't know any airline or country with restrictions on bringing cash in hand luggage. Prohibited items are deemed to be a security risk. I can't imagine what you potentially could do with cash in an airplane cabin, which might be dangerous to others. Customs requirements differ from country to country, so you will have to tell between which two countries you are flying and not just 'two EU countries'.

Comment: You can carry it, but why do you need to carry so much cash? It's far safer to transfer the money using a bank, transferring Euros around Europe is trivial,  and you don't risk losing or being quizzed by customs.

Comment: @gerrit Which is why most (if not all) EU countries require you to declare larger amounts of cash even when travelling between two EU countries. OP is obviously intending to do so, so hiding the money from the authorities does not seem to be the reason in this case.

Comment: @Arthur'sPass You can usually only open a bank account in the country you are resident, so if OP lives in one EU country and needs cash himself in another EU country, transferring the money is not a trviial solution. Perhaps he wants to buy something valuable in another EU country, does not trust the seller enough to transfer the money to an unknown person and therefore wants to pay cash when picking up whatever he has bought.

Comment: The reason why is not the part of the question. I have no intention to do anything illegal.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo There is no need to open a bank account - bank transfers are quick and need not be expensive. If the issue is one of trust then it seems reasonable to transfer the money when the deal is done. A transaction in excess of €10,000 that must be settled in cash will certainly attract the attention of the authorities. In any case, this is all speculation.

Comment: Can you name the two countries in question?

Comment: The details will probably depend on the countries involved (origin, destination, and any country you may transit through). You should most probably have paperwork which explains the origin of the funds, and possibly which justifies what you want to do with it (in many countries, you are not even allowed to pay things in cash over a certain amount). Stacks of paper can show up as suspicious on some scanners, so be prepared to show the stuff to security, who may in turn alert customs or the police, and make sure you have plenty of extra time. Remember that in some places, they can confiscate it.

Comment: Also be prepared for the situation where you may need to reroute through another country not in your original travel plans.

Comment: @Arthur'sPass What exactly do you mean when you say 'bank transfer'. The normal meaning of the term is to transfer money between two bank accounts. Of course both the sender and the recipient need a bank account to do so.

Comment: IMO, if someone asks about how to do something illegal, we tell them it is illegal, and that's it. If someone is going to do something not illegal, but unwise, we tell them it is unwise and perhaps give alternatives. _WHY_ they want to do that thing is not our business to determine.

Comment: Note that some countries may prohibit large cash transactions entirely.  I'm told than in Italy, it's illegal to pay for anything more than (IIRC) €5000 in cash.

Comment: You *can*, but you *shouldn't*. There are all sorts of ways it can and likely will be taken from you, whether by simple theft, deception, or robbery, and it doesn't really matter whether the party taking it has the backing of the state since either way your money is gone. There are all sorts of safe and reasonable ways to move money. Learn how to use them rather than doing something stupid.

Comment: Many EU airports have sniffer dogs trained to detect the smell of banknotes, and you could be asked to open your bag, and explain why you are carrying the cash and where it came from. Even if you aren't arrested and the cash confiscated temporarily or permanently, you could miss a flight and/or be stranded. I was stopped at Bristol because a dog indicated I had banknotes. I showed the guys my 200 Euros I had exchanged for my trip to Spain. They said they were new notes, which got the dog excited. She was a charming spaniel.

Comment: "the reason why is not part of the question" -> and your logic is that if you're snippy with us about your privacy, we won't enquire further. That's great, awesome... but **That will not work at the customs desk**.  They have the liberty *and the duty* to assume you're up to something nefarious. You will have limited ability to rebut that. Since you don't want help crafting that rebuttal, *lotsa luck*.

Comment: Be prepared for how you will act in the airport security checkpoint as the metal in a stack of bank notes will be picked up by the metal detector. I think you should ask for a search in a private room and present the correct paper work (what ever that may be) for reference

Comment: @CGCampbell I'm not aware of any reason for this that isn't illegal. Considering the asker hasn't provided a reason, the question appears even more suspicious.

Comment: Are you ok with it being stolen by baggage handlers? Because it's gonna be stolen.

Comment: @Studoku The OP specifies hand luggage, which I take to mean 'carry on'. Baggage handlers should not be a part of this.

Comment: Note that it most likely will be illegal to pay any business or person with an amount of cash that big. There are laws against big cash payment in most eu countries. But for specifics, we need to know the country and the relation between you and the recipient(s) of the money.

Comment: "I have no intention to do anything illegal." Not declaring the cash is illegal, so that statement is the core of your problem.

Comment: I hope your are not being scammed.

Comment: @Ángel no, this is my money, just want to transfer it to my home country to spend it here. Bank transfer is not an option unfortunately, the fees are to high if the cash is not in EUR.

Comment: I summon the "move to chat" feature as the comments are getting polluted. We have no evidence that the OP is trying to move money illegally or hide them from the authorities. The OP said they "know they need to declare". **We** must act on presumption of bona fide

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Cash must be declared even within Schengen countries.

No fee is due on declared cash. That's your own money! You must call a customs officer at the departure airport and ask to declare money for >10000€ in cash.

The reason is fighting money laundering and tax evasion. The declaration form contains your personal identification data, and your EU individual tax code. You are free to move your own money across countries as soon as you declare them.

Tax authorities will collect declarations and **may** use them <strike>against you</strike> in case of income verification or investigation. Basically you are leaving a trail that you own large amounts of money and that you are moving that money in cash (untraceable) from country A to B.

Tax authorities can already monitor traceable payment methods, and they do use big data computing to find anomalies and investigate *potential* tax evaders.

Conclusion: it is perfectly legal and allowed to bring cash abroad, but you must declare it.

Source: I work in a financial RegTech company and I am familiar with these kind of operations (e.g. compare income, property and expenditures after data submitted by financial operators)

I haven't answered for the part about airlines. You may want to check directly with them with their travel conditions. I would suggest to (passively) read their ToS than calling them. We are still speaking about a lot of money.

Anyway it's the security attendants who will see all that cash in the xray machine for the first time. Airlines don't check luggage themselves.

Comment: “Tax authorities... do use big data computing to find anomalies...” - do you have evidence for this? It sounds a rather modern activity for a government to be using, especially given how old the banking systems often are.

Comment: @Tim there's a reason why some governments are pushing for things like large deposit declarations and automated exchange of banking information between countries, especially from tax heavens or similar jurisdictions. Government can be very innovative when there's money to be collected. https://www.ey.com/en_gl/tax/how-data-analytics-is-transforming-tax-administration https://www.opentext.com/file_source/OpenText/en_US/PDF/opentext-so-analytics-big-data-analytics-for-tax-authorities-en.pdf

Comment: @Tim even if governments aren't, the banks certainly are, as part of their own internal fraud detection and due diligence. My source on that is a former PhD student who got hired by one of the companies the work gets outsourced to.

Comment: @origimbo partially correct. Banks enforce AML because they are required by the law, not because they *like* to fight laundering as a sport (unless they care about their reputation more than money). @Tim Examples or European inter-agency exchanges are FATCA/CRS (where CRS is a derivation of US FATCA), DACx (most recent version is DAC6), VIES and some invasive "expenditure-o-metre" to the IRS (`Italian Revenue Service`) with regards to every individual's e-invoices (from gym to utilities). But that's more of a "personal finance" topic

Comment: Couldn't there still be local regulations to worry about? E.g. there is a proposal to outlaw carrying more then 2k euros cash in the Netherlands in Rotterdam (https://www.rtlnieuws.nl/editienl/artikel/5185906/contant-geld-limiet-cash-op-zak-2000-euro).

Comment: In the US, there have been many instances of large amounts of cash being taken from people using ["civil foreiture"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_forfeiture_in_the_United_States) as the reasoning.

Answer (score 9):

Since you seem to be travelling entirely within the EU [you will need to check with the customs offices of the countries you leave, pass through and enter](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/carry/alcohol-tobacco-cash/index_en.htm#shortcut-3) what the arrangements are, since this hasn't been fully harmonised. As you state in the question, it's likely (but not absolutely guaranteed) that you'll need to fill in a national declaration form, but unlikely for there to be any fee involved.

Unless it involves discrimination law, airlines are usually able to make up their own conditions of carriage, so in theory one could ban the carrying of high value monetary instruments, however I'm not aware of any which go beyond "don't do anything illegal, don't put money in your checked baggage and it's at your own risk as much as we can legally say that".

Comment: I don't see how an *airline* would know.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Random or pseudo-random security spot checks at the gate aren't totally unknown. Not to mention being seen by flight attendants, etc.

Answer (score 3):

> Can I take on-board large sum of cash (more than 10k euros) in my hand luggage?

This may depend on the specific countries involved, bu in general the answer is yes. It is legal to carry as much cash as you want. That DOES NOT MEAN that you are allowed to bring the cash into the country. See the next point:

> I know I need to declare this cash at customs but do I need to pay any fee for that?

Typically there is no fee. HOWEVER, you will get questioned and whether you are allowed to bring the cash in and/or enter the country yourself will depend on the quality & credibility of your story and is up the indivudal customs inspector. You better have a good story and some documentation to back it up.

> Can the airline have any regulations that would prohibit flying with large sum of cash?

They can, but the typically don't. If in doubt, check with the specific airline.

Answer (score 2):

The point is that you might be allowed to carry the cash. Or not. The salient word here is "might".

The border police is required to ask you both where the money comes from and what you are planning to use it for. As we all know, using cash is a way to sever the trail of money and is often used as part of money laundering. And this means that the border police will be, rightly, very suspicous.

Especially the last few years, as SEPA payments are by "European law" required to work both fast and at low cost within EU+, what would the reason be to carry cash.

Purely, as an example, assume that you are planning to buy a car for 20.000 Euro and the seller requires cash. Your part of the transaction might be fully legal, say saved money. But what happens at the other end? Will the seller rightfully declare the money and pay the necessary taxes? Did the seller acquire the car legally? Will the seller use the cash for illegal purposes?

So, the border police might give you the choice of either board the plane or stay and explain the money. You will of course get a receipt and will be able to get the cash back. But are you willing to take the chance?

Comment: Do note that paying 20.000 euro in cash (no matter what you bought) may not be legal in the final country.

Comment: @Ángel Indeed. And what I missed in the answer is that there are two border police forces ( making things simple here, there is both police and toll ) that a traveler would have to convince. One in each country.

Comment: What the seller does with the money is not OP's business. But to stay in your example: OP needs a proper invoice for the car (for warranty, registration, possibly selling the car again later, ...) and that means that it will have to enter the seller's books like any other [small] cash payment. Also, e.g. in Germany, while it is legal to buy a car for 20 k€ in cash the seller would have to do anti money laundering paperwork of an extent that most car selling businesses won't accept such large cash payments.

Answer (score 0):

As opposed to checked baggage?
On your person is better, certainly never in checked baggage.
The airlines prefer this too.

10,000 Euro is not a lot of money, neither is 20,000.  Perhaps we are just poorer than we think we are. It can be hard to find an ATM in many countries. Is Paris still using GPRS for taxi payments? How a city with such a low skyline gets such poor coverage I will never understand, maybe a lack of towers... Better to have a bit of excess than be caught short. You need to share the joy.

A million may be a problem. Do your homework, but again, not in the checked baggage, never. Do not split it across your companions either, that does not go down well.